# Using Psycopg2 in virtualenv (Ubuntu 14.4, Python 3.4)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, psycopg2

I have installed `postgres` and `Psycopg2` using `apt-get` on my linux.

I want to use `postgres` for one of my `django` project.

I have created `virtualenv` but i am not able to work with psycopg2 when i add it in `db settings`.

Here is `setting.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'secondnginxapp',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I run the server and got the error `Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'`

I check installed `psycopg2` with following command.

```
 python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"
```

Output: `2.4.5 (dt dec mx pq3 ext)`

How to use `psycopg2` with virtualenv? need help.

(I am learning python and django)

I tried to install in `virtualenv` as well.

`pip install psycopg2` then error is `Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'`

Then i tried `pip install libpq-dev` now error is `No matching distribution found for libpq-dev`

Comment: Have you tried to use pip to install psycopg2 inside virtualenv? It is possible that you have 2 different versions of python and apt-get installed it just for python2.

Comment: How do you run the server? What command do you use? And is the virtualenv activated?

Comment: @Morishiri Yes i did. please check updated question.

Comment: @jpmc26 virtualenv is activated. I tried `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @shri I think that you have your answer in updated question. Install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y (replace X.Y with version - 9.4 is the newest now afaik - using apt-get)

Comment: @Morishiri I have installed postgress already in system. Do i need to install it again in `virtualenv`?

Comment: @Shri, No. But are you sure you have installed both client and server version of postgresql?
`apt-get install postgresql-X.Y` - for client and
`apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y` for server

Comment: @Morishiri I have only client installation.

Comment: @Shri, install server then :) Then you will be able to execute `pip install psycopg2` inside `virtualenv` and it should work.

Comment: @Morishiri Do the client and sever version needs to be same? I have 9.3 installed as client version

Comment: @Shri I'm not sure about that, but it's better to have matching versions in my opinion. Btw. I will add it as answer. Accept please if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to install server version of postgresql (It seems like you have only client installed). On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y
```

where the `X.Y` is version of the package.

Then, inside `virtualenv` environment install `psycopg2` module:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have used `apt-get` to install the driver, which has installed it in your system python's package directory; and by default the virtual environment is created with no system packages.

So even though the command works when you are outside the virtual environment (using the system Python), it doesn't work inside the virtual environment.

You have two options to fix this:

1. Delete the file `no-global-site-packages.txt` found in your virtual environment's Python installation.

   So if you created a virtual environment at `/home/env/my-env/`, then you would execute `rm /home/env/my-env/lib/python3.4/no-global-site-packages.txt`

   Once that file is removed, the virtual environment will look in the global environment for any missing packages.
2. Install the system libraries that will allow you to build the extension. For ubuntu this is `sudo apt install build-essential python-dev python3.4-dev libpq-dev`. Once you run that command, you can then `pip install psycopg2` in your virtual environment.

Comment: with all respect sir, is it a actual solution?

Comment: Thank you very much for details.